# A more elegant approach to proving independence between $X_{(3)}$ and $X_{(2)}-X_{(3)}$

Tags: probability-theory, order-statistics

For $X_1,X_2,X_3 \sim$i.i.d exponential ($\lambda$), I am trying to show independence between $X_{(3)}$ and $X_{(2)}-X_{(3)}$ where $X_{(3)}$ is the third largest observation, i.e. the minimum in this case.

My attempt:
\begin{align}
P(X_{(2)}-X_{(3)} > x,X_{(3)} >y ) &= P(X_{(2)}-X_{(3)} > x \mid X_{(3)} >y )P(X_{(3)} >y) \\ & = P(X_{(2)}-X_{(3)} > x-y)P(X_{(3)} >y)
\end{align}
By the memorylessness of the exponential. I then go on to derive the the PDF of $X_{(2)}-X_{(3)}$ and show that the above expression is equivalent to $P(X_{(2)}-X_{(3)} > x)P(X_{(3)} >y)$ implying independence. However, this is quite tedious as it requires a lot of computation to figure out the pdf. I think there is a more elegant way to do it using the properties of the exponential but not quite sure how to go about it

Comment: Usually, the minimum is denoted as $X_{(1)}$ and the maximum is $X_{(n)}$...

Comment: @d.k.o. I don't really see the relevance of your post with respect to the question? There are many books that use this convention, and yes the majority use yours..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda=1$ for simplicity and $X_{(1)}=\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$. Then for $x\le y$

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x,y)=3!(1-F_{X_1}(y))f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_1}(y)$$

$X_{(2)}$ given $X_{(1)}$ is the sum of $X_{(1)}$ and an independent  exponential r.v. with parameter 2 because

$$f_{X_{(2)}|X_{(1)}}(y|x)=\frac{3!(1-F_{X_1}(y))f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_1}(y)}{3(1-F_{X_1}(x))^2f_{X_1}(x)}=2e^{-2(y-x)}$$

so that

$$f_{X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}|X_{(1)}}(y|x)=2e^{-2y}=f_{X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}}(y)$$

Comment: how do you get the distributions of $X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} | X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)} - X_{(1)} $ ?

Comment: @dimebucker91:

$$P\{X_{(2)} - X_{(1)}\le c | X_{(1)}=x\}=P\{X_{(2)}\le c+x|X_{(1)}=x\}=1-e^{-2(c+x-x)}=1-e^{-2c}$$

Conditional dist. does not depend on the value of $X_{(1)}\Rightarrow$ it is the same as unconditional:

$$f_{X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}}(c)=\int f_{X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}|X_{(1)}}(c|x)f_{X_{(1)}}(x)dx$$